# How do I remove special characters from the values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
{
'file1.txt': {'address': [],  'ORG': []},
'file2.txt': {'address': [],  'ORG': ['DEF Pvt. Ltd','One Solutions (Asia) Limited' ]}
}
```

I need to remove the special characters from the 'ORG' key.

I know for a normal dictionary we can do`{key.strip(): item.strip() for key, item in my_dict.items()}`

but I'm not sure how to do it for a nested one, any ideas?

Comment: Define "special character"?

Comment: How do you create the dictionary? Wouldn't is be easier to `strip` while creating the dictionary instead of doing it afterwards?

Comment: @Selcuk - I want to remove all non-alpha numberic characters , like .,() etc

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - the dictionary is a result of a NER model, so this is the format in which it produces the output

Comment: I guess this will help you: https://newbedev.com/python-recursively-replace-character-in-keys-of-nested-dictionary This is a pretty way to iterate through nested dictionaries...

Answer (score 1):

According to the unknown number of elements in the `ORG` key, I highly prefer to use two for loops and regex.

So, you need to import the `regex` library and then use `re.sub` which can be used to delete specific characters.

The regex I used in this question is:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]
```

The whole script:

```
import re
myDict = {
'file1.txt': {'address': [],  'ORG': []},
'file2.txt': {'address': [],  'ORG': ['DEF Pvt. Ltd','One Solutions (Asia) Limited' ]}
}
for key, item in myDict.items():
  tempList = myDict[key]["ORG"]
  for index, value in enumerate(tempList):
    tempList[index] = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]", "", value)
  myDict[key]["ORG"] = tempList
print(myDict)
```

**Output**:

```
{
   'file1.txt': {'address': [], 'ORG': []}, 
   'file2.txt': {'address': [], 'ORG': ['DEF Pvt Ltd', 'One Solutions Asia Limited']}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    my_dict['key'] = [char for char not in list_special]
```

Here, list_special is a list of special characters.

if it is a list in the dictionary, you would have to add a nested for loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment before, here is a working solution regardless the depth of the nested dictionary and without any hardcoded key names:

[Original code](https://newbedev.com/python-recursively-replace-character-in-keys-of-nested-dictionary)

Modified code:

```
import re

def change_dict_naming_convention(d, convert_function):
    """
    Convert a nested dictionary from one convention to another.
    Args:
        d (dict): dictionary (nested or not) to be converted.
        convert_function (func): function that takes the string in one convention and returns it in the other one.
    Returns:
        Dictionary with the new keys.
    """

    if isinstance(d, dict):
      new = {}
      for k, v in d.items():
          new_v = v
          if isinstance(v, dict):
              new_v = change_dict_naming_convention(v, convert_function)
          elif isinstance(v, list):
              new_v = list()
              for x in v:
                  new_v.append(change_dict_naming_convention(x, convert_function))
          elif isinstance(v, str):
            new_v = convert_function(v)
          new[convert_function(k)] = new_v
    elif isinstance(d, str):
      new = convert_function(d)
    else:
      new = d

    return new


def convert_function(value):
  return re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\s\.:]", "", value)


orignial_dict: dict = {
'file1.txt': {'address': {'street': 'Any Street No. 22 (a)',
                          'zipCode': 1234,
                          'city': 'AnyCity (Asia)'},  
              'ORG': ['123 (DEF) #Pvt. -Ltd','One Solutions (Asia) Limited']},
'file2.txt': {'address': [],  
              'ORG': ['DEF Pvt. Ltd','One Solutions (Asia) Limited' ]}
}

new_dict: dict = change_dict_naming_convention(orignial_dict, convert_function)

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'file1.txt': {'address': {'street': 'Any Street No. 22 a', 'zipCode': 1234, 'city': 'AnyCity Asia'}, 'ORG': ['123 DEF Pvt. Ltd', 'One Solutions Asia Limited']}, 
 'file2.txt': {'address': [], 'ORG': ['DEF Pvt. Ltd', 'One Solutions Asia Limited']}}
```

I hope this helps you ;)